# Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response error while on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I am developing my React app on localhost:3000 and am using the following code:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('https://myendpoint.com/abcd/search?c=abc123', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  });
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonData);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```

When running this code from the client, I am receiving the following error:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I am also using node express on the server side.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: are you using cors() in your api?

Comment: is the fetch call to your api or another api?

Comment: it's actually another api. any help on how to move call onto the server and change client for this call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code exactly on top of all your routes. So, every request from a foreign host, on the server goes to this request, then after attaching these headers, your first next route which matches with the request URL will run.

```
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        next();
    });
```